# How to hash all passwords from DB using PHP password_hash function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, password-encryption

Is there any possible way to run a query using `password_hash()` function to change all the existent passwords from my users table?

I am using CI and is not working at all!

> My model

```
public function EncryptDB($filters = NULL){
     $ci =& get_instance();
     $ci->load->helper('hash');
     $query = "UPDATE users SET password = {hash_password(password)}";
     $sql = $this->db->query($query);

}
```

*note that i am loading a custom `helper` to hash it.

> My helper

```
function hash_password($password){
        $configs = array(
            "cost" => 10 # custo de processamento (10 -> default)
        );
        $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $configs);

        return $password;
    }
```

> My controller

```
public function EncryptDB(){
             if($this->UsersDAO->EncryptDB()){
                  echo 'done';
             } else {
                  echo 'error';
             }
        }
```

Comment: Unless your passwords are stored in plain text the answer is no.

Comment: give me the users table schema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

1. This solution assumes that the `users` table has a primary key called `id`.
2. I didn't actually run/test this code. But it should give you an idea on how to solve this problem anyways.
3. This code runs inside a transaction so if one record fails to update, then none will.
4. This code should probably be run only once, for a fixed table.

   `function updatePasswords(){`

   ```
   $this->db->trans_start();
       $offset = 0;
       do{
           $selectQuery = $this->db
                               ->limit(100, $offset)
                               ->get('users');
           $results = $selectQuery->result();

           foreach ($results as $user){
               $configs = array(
                   "cost" => 10 # custo de processamento (10 -> default)
               );
               $hashedPassword = password_hash($user->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $configs);
               $this->db
                   ->set('password', $hashedPassword)
                   ->where('id', $user->id)
                   ->update('users');
           }

           $offset += $selectQuery->num_rows();

       } while ($selectQuery->num_rows() > 0);
   $this->db->trans_complete();

   if ($this->db->trans_status()){
       die("[+] operation successfully completed.");
   }
   else{
       die("[-] operation encounted an error somewhere. not data was updated.");
   }
   ```

   `}`

Comment: I've got this error message @marvinIsSacul:
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$password

Comment: what is the primary key then?

Comment: forget it @marvinIsSacul, i wrote a field incorrectly. Your script worked like a charm, thank you so much!